# Issue with Dapper and Informix Text data types

Tags: exception, text, dapper, informix

I have a .NET library that has functionality to insert rows into an Informix table. One of the fields in this table is of the TEXT data type. This code utilises Dapper (1.42.0).

Recently, the code spontaneously broke with the following error.

> ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Illegal attempt to convert Text/Byte blob type."}  System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException

The exception bubbles up from the ODBC driver, through Dapper's SQLMapper class.

Eventually, it was discovered that the problem coincided with a Windows update which appears to have broken functionality with Dapper itself. To test this theory, updates were removed and functionality restored. Unfortunately, I have not had time to isolate the specific update.

To be more specific, using ordinary ODBC types in .NET works fine.

Also using dynamic parameters and anonymous typing works fine with Dapper as well. Here's a console app just as an example;

```
private static void TestDapperAnon()
    {
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            DynamicParameters dparams = new DynamicParameters();
            dparams.Add("?note?", $"Adding a note #{new Random().Next(1000)}", System.Data.DbType.String, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

            cn.Open();
            int result = cn.Execute(query, dparams);
            Console.WriteLine("result was " + result);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

What breaks the code is the use of the strongly-type version of the query with Dapper:

```
private static void TestDapperStronglyTyped()
    {
        Notepad pad = new Notepad
        {
            id = 0,
            note_id = 999,
            created = DateTime.Now,
            user = "USER",
            note = "meh"
        };
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            int result = cn.Execute(query, pad);
            Console.WriteLine("result was " + result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I can't show the notepad type for security reasons, but its property names match the field names exactly, as per Dapper's documentation. I suspect it has something to do with how Dapper maps type properties to parameter values.

My question is whether anyone has encountered this issue recently and whether they have any suggestions as to a fix?

**UPDATE**

Having found time to delve in this issue a little more, I discovered quite by accident that if I adjust the Size property of the command parameter, I can avoid the exception.
The dynamic parameters generated by Dapper have a Size property of 4000. By accident, I discovered that if you set this property to 8001 using debugging tools, the exception can be avoided. I have no idea why it is 8001.

I'm guessing, but I suspect the Dapper logic sets a default size of 4000 when it generates dynamic parameters based on the string type. (E.g. See SqlMapper.cs, line 2648).

I am now left wondering whether it possible to override this default behaviour.

Comment: We can debate the spontaneity of the breakage given that there was a software upgrade that broke what had been working.  We might even argue that the new version of Dapper broke backwards compatibility — probably consciously.  However, those observations don't help fix the problem.  I'm not clear how your `Notepad` type is supposed to transfer data to the `cn.Execute()` method — I'm not a C# programmer (I spell C without any extra characters).  I suspect you will need to specify a type for `note` somewhat like you did with the `dparams` variant, but I've no idea how that would be done.

Comment: I don't know if seeing the way `query` is defined and set up would help; I suspect not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suspect it was the windows update that broke Dapper.
I haven't dived into the Dapper code, though it is open source. From what I know it uses .NET Reflection to map the type properties to the query parameters. I do appreciate that you have taken the time and trouble to comment.

Comment: The TEXT type in Informix is a peculiar type, requiring special handling in all sorts of ways.  There aren't simple conversions from character strings, for example, to the TEXT type, for tedious hysterical raisins (oops — historical reasons).  The BYTE type is analogous.  You might do better using the CLOB type (or its binary analogue, the BLOB type).  OTOH, you may be better where you are.  Another possibility might be LVARCHAR if you don't need to store megabytes of data in the columns (up to a few kilobytes at most) — and LVARCHAR is a comparatively simple and sane type.

Comment: Have you try adding "NEEDODBCTYPESONLY" to the connection string or choosing "Report Standard ODBC Types Only" in the ODBC DSN ("Advanced" tab) defintion?
That will enable some internal functions within the ODBC driver to automatically handle CLOB/BLOB types.